# Building Lua for C++

Tags: c++, gcc, lua, g++

According to the Lua Wiki, if Lua 5.1 or later is compiled as C++, it will use C++ exceptions. Since Lua is a C library it only references CC in the makefile. So, my idea was to redefine CC as "g++" so I don't have to modify the makefile.

```
make generic CC="g++"
```

I was able to build Lua without any problems. However, now when I link my C++ application to the Lua (static) library I receive undefined reference errors for many Lua functions (lua_checklstring, lua_pushinteger, etc).

When I build Lua using using gcc my application links successfully.

```
make generic CC="gcc"
```

Am I compiling Lua for C++ incorrectly? I assume I need to use g++ somehow since the Lua source code contains preprocessor checking for cplusplus to determine if C++ exceptions should be enabled.

Comment: Which lua header are you including in your C++ project (lua.h or lua.hpp)? And are you using extern "C" with it?

Comment: I am using lua.hpp. I am not using extern "C" around lua.hpp since lua.hpp already does that. Should I be including lua.h (without extern "C") since my Lua library is now a C++ library (rather than a C library)?

Comment: Correct. `extern "C"` avoids the C++ name mangling which you need done since your library was built as C++.

Comment: It sounds like the compiled lua runtime is getting its api function names mangled. Can you check your compiled static library with `objdump` or `nm` and verify that the names aren't mangled?

Comment: Also see http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to the original question, I was including lua.hpp in my C++ application. This worked well when Lua was compiled as a C library since lua.hpp undos name mangling:

```
lua.hpp:

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

As pointed out by @EtanReisner, when using Lua as a C++ library instead I do not need to undo the name mangling. So the solution was to simply include the actual Lua headers, rather than lua.hpp

```
// Using Lua as a C library
#include <lua.hpp>

// Using Lua as a C++ library
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
```