# Undefined reference to Lua C++ library functions

Tags: c++, gcc, lua

I am try to use Lua 5.3.3 scripting in my c++ project, I am compiling with gcc, code::blocks. I get errors when I try to use Lua functions, such as newstate().

main.cpp:

```
#include <lua/lua.hpp>
// ...

int main()
{
    lua_State *state = luaL_newstate();
    lua_close(state);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

errors:

> ||=== Build: Debug in MettaRPG (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   obj\Debug\src\main.o||In function 'main':|
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\Coding\CodeBlocks\MettaRPG\src\main.cpp|12|**undefined**
>   **reference to 'luaL_newstate'**|
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\Coding\CodeBlocks\MettaRPG\src\main.cpp|13|**undefined
>   reference to 'lua_close'**| ||error: ld returned 1 exit status| ||===
>   Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

possible duplicates:

> ["Undefined reference to" using Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060009/undefined-reference-to-using-lua)
>   Did not solve my problem when I tried it. It yielded the same errors.
>
> [Lua 5.3 undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084681/lua-5-3-undefined-references)
>   I am using this in my program, but it still doesn't work.
>
> [Building Lua for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839883/building-lua-for-c) Also
>   doens't fix my problem.

Comment: That's a linker error, most likely because you aren't linking the lua library properly.

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue. I hadn't correctly included Lua. I resolved this by installing a prebuilt **dynamic** library, putting the *.c* and *.h* files in include, and the *.a* files in the lib file, the *.dll* files in the project's main directory. I had to go to build settings and link in the include and library folder. Download the prebuilt library from here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaBinaries